# How to bring up a precise Emoji in the iOS QuickType menu

Tags: ios, text-input, emoji, keyboard

In **iOS 10**, the **QuickType** menu is a lifesaver whenever the user needs to type a long word and doesn't feel like typing it (and it's also fun to make up [silly sentences](https://www.theverge.com/2014/9/17/6337105/breaking-apples-quicktype-keyboard)).

It also randomly suggests Emojis. But finding what to type to make the intended Emoji appear can be quite discouraging. For example if I want to type the "[Smiling Face With Horns](https://emojipedia.org/smiling-face-with-horns/)"  there doesn't seem to be a way to QuickType it without having to go in the Emoji Keyboard. See examples below showing attempts at entering "Demon", "Evil" and "Devil":

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My questions:**

- Can all the Emojis be called through QuickType without having to go into the Emoji Keyboard?
- How do I know how what to type to call the right ones?

Comment: Have you tried adding the emoji to the text replacement feature of the keyboard settings (General > Keyboard > Text Replacement)? Say (just for example) every time you typed <devil> you got  as a replacement.  Quicktype might pick up on the frequent usage of <devil> and offer it up as a suggestion.

Comment: Sounds a bit tedious for all the emojis out there! My question is more about whether or not there is a list of which words call up which emojis, if that's how it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer both of your questions:

1. No, you cannot type all emoji using QuickType. It's currently not possible to quicktype .
2. See below.

Examples that can be typed:
 star struck
 Japan
 video game controller

Examples that do not adhere to Unicode descriptions:
 controller ("trackball" does not work)

You can test most matches on macOS using the Emoji & Symbols popup: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Examples that can be typed on macOS (10.13.3), but not iOS (11.2.6):
 jockey ("jockey on racing horse")
 zany ("zany face")

On macOS the localised keyword data is inside  `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework` spread across 4 strings files:

1. `AppleName.strings` (descriptive name) [1549 entries in English]
2. `CharacterPicker.strings` (for searching) [1505 entries]
3. `FindReplace.strings` (for suggestions/predictive) [1060 entries]
4. `Voiceover.strings` (for macOS speech) [1764 entries]

Quickly comparing `FindReplace.strings` with `AppleName.strings` or any other complete list of Emoji shows that some are missing.

Also, iOS seems to be lagging with regards to its copy of this data.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a source for #1?

Comment: @MicroMachine have expanded my answer to show that iOS is missing some that can be typed on macOS.

Comment: @MicroMachine have updated my answer quoting actual data.

Comment: Thanks Matt, great answer! I am trying your dictionary but I'm not sure how. Congrats anyways!

Comment: @MicroMachine thanks! It was actually quite useful to hunt out this data, as I may use it as the/a source for my Emoji Dictionary. There's another good answer in the methods I used to track it down. ;)

Comment: Are there any resources you could share on how either the `.strings` files are composed or how to read / write the `.strings` files in Swift? I'm looking at these files in the Atom text editor and I'm not sure how their formatted to create the map like: : star struck and : Japan

Comment: @jonobr1 hit me up on twitter or through my website, this isn't the best place for this