# Find text to trigger a particular emoji in Predictive Keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard, emoji

Sometimes, iPhone suggests emojis based on the text you have typed, like so [image]

I have been trying to trigger this emoji  on the Predictive bar shown above without success. I know there is some personalization involved, but is there a way to find the text that can trigger a particular emoji? I would think there is are some default text mapping to each emoji.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, the word you want is any of:

- crazy
- lol
- laughing
- lolz
- lols
- lulz
- rotfl
- rotflmao
- excited
- silly
- loco

On macOS the list of words for the suggestion/predictive feature is in `FindReplace.strings` within `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework`, but the majority of the keywords work on iOS too.

There are different sets of words for each language, as you would expect.

Also see: [How to bring up a precise Emoji in the iOS QuickType menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316146/how-to-bring-up-a-precise-emoji-in-the-ios-quicktype-menu/316816#316816)

Comment: Based on your suggestion I was able to find someone who had posted the contents of the file: https://gist.github.com/zats/35b2f5bbe5ae72a2efb7793098be10dd

Comment: @jlevis copy-paste that list and make it a solution, save us all a click

Comment: now that I have a good list, am trying to figure out how to select an emoji on mac iMessage without having to toggle the finicky `fn` key shortcut... wish I had the slack-like :thumbsup:`tab`

Comment: Seems we can now do a sequence like `fn` `ok` ⬇️ ⏎ 

Yet again, _think different_

Answer (score 1):

Apple probably has their own list of mappings between words and emojis(for various languages). They probably use some of the Unicode data([here](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-data.txt) is some that I found - digging through the Unicode website you could find more).